# What is a basis for the vector space of continuous functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, axiom-of-choice, hamel-basis

A natural vector space is the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Is there a nice basis for this vector space? Or is this one of those situations where we're guaranteed a basis by invoking the Axiom of Choice, but are left rather unsatisfied?

Comment: This is what Mick Jagger was singing about.

Comment: [Cue the AC guys...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/does-mathbbr-mathbbr-have-a-basis#comment207262_88038) Oh wait, that's me. Let me write something up. :-)

Comment: Hmmm. Since I don't see how the continuous functions make a Polish group, I can't really use the "usual" tools for this sort of proof. I think it is *very* unlikely that a Hamel basis exists without the aid of the axiom of choice here. If I can come up with a clean argument I'll post it later today.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Some papers by Lorenz Halbeisen at http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~halbeis/publications/publications.html may be relevant (perhaps not directly, but the references might be helpful), such as #5, 9, 21.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the reference! I actually ran into some of those before. Is the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is a Banach space at all? What is the metric? I know it is true if the domain was compact, but alas $\mathbb R$ is not compact and $\mathbb Q$ is even less compact than that.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Off-hand, I don't know about the case for $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R,$ but I suppose one would need to restrict attention to bounded functions (continuous, or whatever). I don't know much functional analysis, but it seems to me that for topological issues you could just use the sup norm for the arctangents of the functions. But maybe I'm talking nonsense . . .

Comment: @Dave: The question here, however, asks about all the continuous functions so we have to have all of them. Proving that a subspace does not have a basis is not enough because it is possible to have a space which has a basis and a subspace without a basis.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: How about if we equip $C(\mathbb{R})$ with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.  This gives us a separable Frechet space and in particular a Polish vector space.  Now can you tell us about your "usual" tools?

Comment: @Nate: Well, we know that Polish groups make a nice object in these contexts; and correct me if my understanding is lacking this is even a Banach space (which makes things even easier). I will consider it in depth in a while, I have to run and give a lecture now. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: No, it isn't Banach.  Every nonempty open set in this topology contains a line.

Comment: @copper.hat, "you can't always get what you want" or "I can get no satisfaction"? Both apply!

Comment: @Nate: Well, a Polish groups gives me "enough" to work with. I'll post some answer soon.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is, in a fairly strong sense, no reasonable basis of this space. Zoom in on a neighborhood at any point and note that a finite linear combination of functions which have various kinds of nice behavior in that neighborhood also has that nice behavior in that neighborhood (differentiable, $C^k$, smooth, etc.). So any basis necessarily contains, for *every such neighborhood*, a function which does not behave nicely in that neighborhood. More generally, but roughly speaking, a basis needs to have functions which are at least as pathological as the most pathological continuous functions.

(Hamel / algebraic) bases of most infinite-dimensional vector spaces simply are not useful. In applications, the various topologies you could put on such a thing matter a lot and the notion of a [Schauder basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) becomes more useful.

Comment: That is probably the best explanation I've seen as to why not to usel Hamel bases in real/complex function spaces. +1!

Answer (score 13):

Using Nate Eldredge's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136637/what-is-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-continuous-functions#comment347999_136637) we have that $C(\mathbb R)$ is a Polish vector space.

Consider a Solovay model, that is ZF+DC+"All sets have the Baire property". In such model all linear maps into separable vector spaces are continuous, this is a consequence of [1, Th. 9.10].

It is important to remark that a continuous function (from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$) from a compact set is uniformly continuous is a result which do not require *any* form of choice, and I believe that Dependent Choice (DC) ensures that uniform converges on compact sets is well behaved.

Suppose that there was a Hamel basis, $B$, it has to be of cardinality $\frak c$. So it has $2^\frak c$ many permutations, which induce $2^\frak c$ **different** linear automorphisms.

However every linear automorphism is automatically continuous, so it is determined completely by the countable dense set, and therefore there can only be $\frak c$ many linear automorphisms which is a contradiction to Cantor's theorem since $\mathfrak c\neq 2^\frak c$.

This is essentially the same argument as I used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122723/622).

---

Bibliography:

1. Kechris, A. **[Classical Descriptive Set Theory.](http://books.google.com/books?id=pPv9KCEkklsC)** *Springer-Verlag*, 1994.

Comment: Very nice!  So in fact one certainly needs the full axiom of choice, and DC is not enough.

Comment: @Nate: Indeed. DC itself is often not enough. Shelah even showed that DC($\aleph_1$) is not enough to have sets without the Baire property!

Answer (score 3):

I'll use faith to believe we are in one of those situations described by the axiom of choice ; had one discovered a useful basis for this vector space, it'd be known all over the place. The best we have as a basis right now, (and the word "best" means 'to my belief, the one that looks the prettiest') is the fact that the functions $e^{inx}$ with $n \in \mathbb Z$ form a Schauder basis of the Hilbert space $L^2([a,b])$ of $\mathbb C$-valued functions (modulo functions which are zero almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ ; note that this is *not* a Hamel basis). For real valued functions, take the functions $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ as your basis.

Hope that helps,

Comment: just a remark on your last claim - that's not literally true since you need to take convergent infinite "linear combinations" whereas in the definition for a basis for a vector space, finite linear combinations give you everything.

Comment: Hamel basis is what you want here.

Comment: Patrick, do you mean $e^{inx}$?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in my comment ; indeed, all what you said was correct, and was what I meant, I just wrote it in a hurry with my mobile phone. Now that I am at home in front of my computer I can see that I wrote too sketchy =) Thanks for the comments.

Comment: The "topological" basis is called Schauder basis.

Comment: @Downvoter : Downvoting without commenting is an insult.