# Basis of vector space of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: vector-spaces

The set of real functions has the structure of a vector space, and all vector spaces have basis. What is the basis of this space then? My first thought was maybe using taylor series but still there are a lot of functions that can not be expressed through taylor series and a linear combination can not have infinite elements (I think). Is there a known basis to this vector space? Is there a way to find it?

Comment: Not even the vector space of continuous functions has a 'nice' basis, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136637/what-is-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-continuous-functions). One needs to use the axiom of choice to find a basis.

Comment: "all vector spaces have basis".... says who?

Comment: @EmmaK Most Linear Algebra books that assume the the Axiom of Choice.